# Flutter default value for a Function

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am currently learning a course on Flutter. They provide you with an old stub project (nullable).
When I try to migrate to Flutter 2.12.0 or higher - null safety kicks in.
I have a basic understanding on how it works - but this I cannot find anywhere on Google or StackOverFlow.

I have a custom Card widget. It requires a Color parameter. Also I need it to be able to receive a Widget child parameter as well as an onPress Function, but I don't want to make them required.
Please, help. How do I create a default value for Widgets and Functions?

```
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableCard({@required this.cardColor, this.cardChild, this.onPress});
  final Color cardColor;
  final Widget cardChild;
  final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        child: cardChild,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          color: cardColor,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make them nullable fields as follows

```
  ReusableCard({required this.cardColor, this.cardChild, this.onPress});
  final Color cardColor;
  final Widget? cardChild;
  final VoidCallback? onPress;
```

Answer (score 1):

- **For nullable function, use `?`**

  ```dart
  class FooWidget extends StatelessWidget {
    final Function? onPressed; // <-- Nullable, use '?'

    FooWidget({
      this.onPressed,
    });

    // ... 
  }
  ```
- **For non-nullable function, use `required`**

  ```dart
  class FooWidget extends StatelessWidget {
    final Function onPressed; // <-- Non-nullable

    FooWidget({
      required this.onPressed, // <-- Use 'required'
    });

    // ...
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

just change

```
final Function onPress;
```

to

```
final Function() onPress;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-variables.

You would define your variables as

```
late final Widget cardChild; 
late final Function onPress;
```

and then initialize them in your constructor (or initState for State objects) before using them.

Comment: Default value of an optional parameter must be constant